# Using QFileSystemModel in PySide, getting the item from the index

Tags: qt, pyside, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel, qmodelindex

I had a look for the answer to this but couldn't find anything on here so I'm asking it.

With `QStandardModel` it is fairly straight forward to get the item from the `QModelIndex` with the command function `itemFromIndex`.

```
model = openedIndex.model()
item = model.itemFromIndex(openedIndex)
```

I'm interested in doing basically the same but for `QFileSystemModel`, is there an easy or straight forward way for me to do this. Couldn't see anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QFileSystemModel` doesn't have any item class. It doesn't create an object for each item.

You may find `QFileSystemModel::filePath` and `QFileSystemModel::index` methods useful. They allow to convert index to path and vice versa. Both index and path can be used as unique item identifier.

Disabling some items in `QFileSystemModel` is not possible directly. You need to create a proxy model class that will return almost the same data and flags as the source model but remove `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` flag when needed.

Comment: Then if that is not the case, any ideas how I might go about disabling it's items. If I set filtering the items get disabled so I assume it must be possible?

Comment: It's not possible directly. You need to create a proxy model class that will return almost the same data and flags as the source model but remove `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` flag when needed.

Comment: I have created a proxy model, how would I go about removing the `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` flag using the proxy model.

Comment: Pavel Strakhov, you gave me the answer I needed to change ItemIsEnabled to false if you would like to add it as an answer I will mark it as correct.